# Incomplete JSON Parsing in Android

Tags: android, json, api

I'm trying to parse JSON from the following URL from Google Civic, but Android is not returning all the data.

https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=AIzaSyDfeiCRXoUEb2ZNaq9WmgadSmeEKAiCIlw&address=TX

Specifically, when the "while-readLine" loop reads, at the top of the feed, I noticed that it is leaving out the opening bracket and the "normalizedInput" phrase. My code is as follows:

```
class GetRepresentatives extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Representative>
{

    HttpURLConnection connector=null;
    JSONObject rawRepresentativeData;
    String googleURL="https://www.googleapis.com/civicinfo/v2/representatives?key=AIzaSyDfeiCRXoUEb2ZNaq9WmgadSmeEKAiCIlw&address=";

    @Override
    protected Representative doInBackground(String... strings) {


        String rawData="";

        try {
            URL currentInput = new URL(googleURL + "TX");

            connector=(HttpURLConnection) currentInput.openConnection();

            connector.connect();

            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connector.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();

            while(reader.readLine() != null) {
                System.out.println(reader.readLine());
            }



            reader.close();

            System.out.println(rawData);
            rawRepresentativeData=new JSONObject(rawData);

            System.out.println();



        }
        catch(Exception iiee)
        {
            System.out.println(iiee.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the BufferedReader correctly!

Every time you check reader.readLine() is already read a line which you are throwing away, that's why lines are missing.

```
 String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```